# Retrieving user information from Parse in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get user information (email address) from Parse. I have tried the following code, but it displays an error, saying that "Anyobject is not convertible to String". What am I supposed to do to get the email address? Thanks in advance.

```
  //Retrieve user info from parse 
    var query:PFQuery=PFQuery(className: "_User");

    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            let user = PFUser.currentUser()
            var email = user["email"] as! String
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is working fine.

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni Well I get an error "'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'" at the line with "var email = user["email"] as! String"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a PFUser.currentUser you can just fetch that object without a query like so

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (currentUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

// Update your data

                    if let user = currentUser as? PFUser {

                        var email = user.email

                    }
                })
```

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly. I have another question. If I have another column of profile pictures within the User class in Parse, how do I get a profile picture of that particular user?

Comment: You can get data from a parse object's key using subscripting, in the above example inside the if let, you would use var photo =  user["columnNameOnParse"] as? PFFile

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
var email = currentUser["email"]
```

This way you will get the email of the current user

Comment: If user have custom columns (Ex : age), how do you retrieve that? What can be user query?